# Split for line issue

Tags: java, templates, split

I have a code:

```
public static CuttingTemplate parseCuttingTemplate(String[] lines) {


        int size = lines.length;
        int[] arr = new int[size];

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            if (i == 0) {
                arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(lines[i]);
            }

            if (i >= 1) {
                arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(lines[i]);
            }
        }

        int width = arr[0];
        int height = arr[0];
        CuttingTemplate ct = new CuttingTemplate(width, height);
        return ct;
    }
```

I need to find a way to add a `.split(";")` and `.split("->")` to my lines. The txt file is ready to read and now i just have to add a "rule" to it but I am not sure where to...

Answer (score 1):

You want to split the text by `;` and `->`? Also the if statements within the loop are unnecessary as they both perform the same action regardless so `arr[i] = integer...` by itself should go the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but based on your identical `arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(lines[i]);` lines, I assume you want to split on `;` in one case and split on `->` in the other case. Your `lines[i]` are the individual `String` lines you're looping over, so you could do something like this:

```
if (i == 0) {
  String[] splitBySemicolon = lines[i].split(";");
  // Get the integer before the ';':
  arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitBySemicolon[0]);
  // or alternatively:
  // Get the integer after the ';':
  arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitBySemicolon[1]);
}
// Minor note: you loop in the range [0, size),
// so you can just use an else here since i cannot be negative
else{
  String[] splitByArrow = lines[i].split("->");
  // Get the integer before the '->':
  arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitByArrow[0]);
  // or alternatively:
  // Get the integer after the '->':
  arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitByArrow[1]);
}
```

For example, let's say your lines array contains `["1;header", "3->something", "4->somethingMore"]`, the code above (using `[0]` for the indexing of the String-arrays), would result in `arr = [1, 3, 4]`.

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##lZI9b8IwEIZ3fsXJC4loDFU71S1Su1QdmBhRBgMHMXXsyDYgivLb08sHEerHwHS5u9fv@1jOTh5kslt/VtVKS@9hJpU5DwCK/VKrFfggA5WDVWvIaRXNg1Nmu0hBxrUMoB9oZdDDCxg89sMzuxcZyjU6dgfsIZl6m2PIaFf3j1f9zDpkpRg0nsoE8OoLya1x5RrNNmTisqzjneuy6r4Wp93hjXVRbaBoPxFUnhsv@hqNOmYy2UBEAlLEcJld3cUXWoW30xxztbLamgvIQqW82UVMsFj0B8djeMcAIcMaB7foYIkEgs1oKIZPvZTAyYUMP1ohL6TzSE30M3QxSfuIsquoPf7P@@qcPf7BmkxvgE2mt9A2kb9Jy/Yt5icfMOd2H3hBqEGbiLUvx2AEO/r3@D4ozclFnjwPtr1RRJq4cSwHZVV9Aw)

But without knowing your actual `lines` array, I can only guess your intended behavior.

Comment: Exactly. My templates are looking like this           300;300
20;20->20;80
20;80->80;80
80;80->80;20
80;20->20;20
100;100->100;266
100;266->266;266
266;266->266;100
266;100->100;100
0;0->300;300             from line 1 to 10 for example